# variable strings concatenation in macro in C

Tags: c, pointers, macros, string-concatenation

Below is a function returning a pointer to string, and this function is polymorphism, which means it could return any classmate's name.

```
const char* get_classmate_name(void);
```

Here is a task that asks you to put/get classmate's information into/from in `info.txt` under each classmate's folder, for example:

```
/good_class/Anderson/info.txt/
/good_class/Cindy/info.txt/
/good_class/Lily/info.txt/
```

I attempted to define those attributes with define macro:

```
#define CLASS_PATH "/good_class"
#define CLASSMATE_PATH CLASS_PATH##"/"get_classmate_name() //wrong
#define CLASSMATE_INFO_PATH CLASSMATE_PATH"/info.txt"
```

Obviously, the second macro is wrong because it's not allowed to concatenate symbolic constant, in this case `CLASS_PATH`, with `const char*` by using `##` operator.

I want program to be simple such like

```
static bool folder_is_found(const char* folder_path);

int main(void)
{
    if ((!folder_is_found(CLASS_PATH)) || (!folder_is_found(CLASSMATE_PATH)))
    {
        reutrun -1;
    }

    const char* classmate_height = get_classmate_height(CLASSMATE_INFO_PATH);
    printf("classmate's height is :%s", classmate_height);

    return 0;
}
```

How to correctly define `CLASSMATE_PATH`?

Comment: Why do you need the **;** in your **#define**

Comment: The ; will cause an error here - `(!folder_is_found(CLASSMATE_PATH)))`

Comment: Thanks. I corrected this typo!

Comment: I see two types of concatenations in your example: `##` and adjacent literals. They both work at compile time and cannot be applied to result of a function as it's runtime value.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want to iterate over that directory and get the names dynamically?

Comment: You cannot use a macro to concatenate a string literal with the result of a function call. A preprocessor macro is text replacement at compile time. (simplified) So the result of your macro will be the string literal followed by the function name which is a syntax error. What you could do is to define a C function that does the concatenation and use this function in the macro definition.

Comment: `char buffer[PATH_MAX]; snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/good_class/%s/info.txt", get_classmate_name())` might be what you are looking for... Or print all three parts into format string `"%s/%s/%s"`.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not functions even if sometimes they look similar.

1. Macros are evaluated **before** the C code compilation starts. The preprocessor does not know anything about C language.
2. `##` concatenated tokens in macro during the preprocessing stage (ie before C code compilation). `##` does something completely different than a concatenation of the adjacent **string literals** (both have to be string literals and concatenation happens compile time, not run time).

You need to use functions instead of macros to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define `CLASSMATE_PATH` as a macro, because the classmate's name (obtained via `get_classmate_name()`) is only known at run-time, and not at compile-time.

A possible function you may use in order to concatenate multiple strings at once is [`snprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```c
char* get_classmate_path(void) {
  const size_t max_path_size = 200;

  char* res = malloc(max_path_size);
  if (res == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  int bytes = snprintf(res, max_path_size, "%s/%s", CLASS_PATH, get_classmate_name());

  if (bytes < 0 || (size_t) bytes >= max_path_size) {
    free(res);
    return NULL;
  }

  return res;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("Classmate path: %s\n", get_classmate_path());
  // POSSIBLE OUTPUT: Classmate path: /good_class/Anderson
}
```

It is trivial, then, to concatenate even more strings together:

```c
char* get_classmate_info_path(void) {
  const size_t max_path_size = 200;

  char* res = malloc(max_path_size);
  if (res == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  int bytes = snprintf(res, max_path_size, "%s/%s/info.txt", CLASS_PATH, get_classmate_name());

  if (bytes < 0 || (size_t) bytes >= max_path_size) {
    free(res);
    return NULL;
  }

  return res;
}
```

NOTE: the previous examples make use of dynamic memory allocation (via `malloc()`); you may want to have a detailed look at how dynamic memory works in C (for instance, you should call `free()` after you're done using the result of `get_classmate_path()`, but that's out of answer's scope).

NOTE 2: the previous functions (`get_classmate_path()` and `get_classmate_info_path()`) may return `NULL` in case of errors.

Comment: Pedantic point:  `if (bytes < 0 || (size_t) bytes >= max_path_size) {` --> `if (bytes < 0 || (unsigned) bytes >= max_path_size) {`.  `size_t` may narrow the `int` value in rare cases where range of `int` exceeds `SIZE_MAX`.  `(unsigned) bytes` never loses info when `bytes >= 0`.